# How to GROUP BY and sum when column names are the same with SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table column names:

```
id_x | id_y | ts | data_a | data_b | data_c
```

I am running this query:

```
SELECT ts, data_a, data_b, data_c from table 
WHERE id_x=4392 
AND id_y IN (2545,2614,3349,4430) 
AND ts BETWEEN '2017-02-01' AND '2017-03-01'
```

I get a result that looks like this:

```
2017-02-01 | 4   | 4  | 0
2017-02-01 | 140 | 30 | 29
2017-02-02 | 4   | 4  | 0
2017-02-02 | 289 | 63 | 60
```

The `ts` field is listed more than once. 
I prefer to have it once and sum it's cells contents.
Is it possible to group the `ts` (timestamp) column is such way?

wanted result:

```
2017-02-01 | 144 | 34  | 29
2017-02-02 | 293 | 67  | 60
```

Comment: Did you try anything, such as `SUM`?

Comment: "How to GROUP BY and sum ..." - with `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `sum()` aggregation and `group by` clause

```
SELECT ts, sum(data_a), sum(data_b), sum(data_c) from table 
WHERE id_x=4392 
AND id_y IN (2545,2614,3349,4430) 
AND ts BETWEEN '2017-02-01' AND '2017-03-01' 
group by ts
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to extract the date and aggregate:

```
SELECT DATE(ts) as ts_date, SUM(data_a) as data_a,
       SUM(data_b) as data_b, SUM(data_c) as data_c 
FROM table 
WHERE id_x = 4392 AND 
      id_y IN (2545, 2614, 3349, 4430) AND
      ts >= '2017-02-01' AND
      ts < '2017-03-01'
GROUP BY DATE(ts) ;
```

Notes:

- This extracts the date from the timestamp.  Presumably, there is a time component.
- `GROUP BY` and `SUM()` do the processing you wnat.
- The date conditions in the `WHERE` clause have been changed so you get all values for February and none for March.

If you want the date range to include the first of March, use:

```
      ts >= '2017-02-01' AND
      ts < '2017-03-02'
```

This construct -- with `>=` and `<` -- works for both dates and date/times.  I strongly recommend that you not use `BETWEEN` with date/time data types because the results can be misleading.

Comment: `not use BETWEEN with date/time data types because the results can be misleading` Can you just explain this when you got time, how you mean misleading? I thought BETWEEN  does exactly like `>= and <=`

Comment: @Veljko89, have a read [here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)